# Fix virtualmin domains to use individual php ini files

Tags: php, apache2, virtualmin

My server is setup to use virtualmin for managing configurations. In trying to resolve a php issue when a wordpress plugin installation, I inadvertently broke the settings on my domains so they no longer use the individual php ini files in their subfolder, but instead all point back to the server's main php.ini file under /etc. I can't seem to find the apache or php configuration to revert the behavior so that it looks for it in the domain's subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-specify-a-custom-php.ini-for-a-website-apache2-with-mod_php/) you can use this setting in Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
[...]
PHPINIDir /path/to/new/ini
[...]
</VirtualHost>
```